# Why IE7 do not remember password for intranet pages?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Why doesn't IE7 remember passwords for intranet pages, when Firefox does?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably just a security "feature" of IE7. Its possible you could change that in the local intranet settings.

(Right click on the icon on the desktop and hit Properties then navigate to the security tab)

Comment: no not working. site is not on LAN it's on server but we use for internal purpose . not accessibile by others

Comment: So it's not on the intranet, but on the inTERnet, right? But secured from others by a login that you want the browser to remember, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Content-->Auto Compete setting?

Alternatively:

1. go to tools>options>security
2. select trusted sites and click sites button
3. add your site to the list
4. log in once and check save my password.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ***http*** or an ***https*** address? For the latter I think that it will not possible to store or autocomplete the password.

Comment: We have a https intranet. IE stores the usernames and passwords just fine.